# Spring.NET, C#, Dependency Injection and transactions

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, transactions, spring.net

I am currently starting development of a ASP.NET project using MVC3, Spring.NET and FluentNHibernate.

My background is mainly java, but with a some Spring framework exposure, so Spring.NET should be easy, peasy, right?

The application architecture is fairly vanilla, with Controllers using Services, Services using DAOs and DAOs using NHibernate Entities and Mappings.

At the moment, I am scratching my head at the current scenario:

One of my service methods uses a Dao, which is injected using spring.net.  When I annotate the service method with the [Transaction] attribute, the DAO dependency ceases to be injected into my service, causing NullReferenceExceptions.

Any ideas as to why this might happen will be greatly appreciated.

Some code to illustrate the problem.  This is not the actual code, but it is pretty close. First the abstract test class, which extends the spring class AbstractTransactionalSpringContextTests :

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Namespace.Dao;
using Namespace.Entities;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Spring.Testing.Microsoft;

namespace Namespace.Tests.Services
{

  [TestClass]
  public class AbstractServiceTest : AbstractTransactionalSpringContextTests
  {
    public AbstractServiceTest()
    {
    }


    protected override string[] ConfigLocations
    {
      get { return new string[]
          {
             "assembly://Assembly/Namespace.Config/dao.xml",
             "assembly://Assembly/Namespace.Config/Services.xml",
             "assembly://Assembly/Namespace.Config/web.xml"
          }; 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This class is extended to create the actual test class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Namespace.Entities;
using Namespace.Services.Assets;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace Namespace.Tests.Services
{
  [TestClass]
  public class AssetsServiceTest : AbstractServiceTest
  {

    public AssetsServiceTest()
    {
    }

    private AssetsService assetsService;

    public AssetsService AssetsService
    {
      get { return assetsService; }
      set { assetsService = value; }
    }


   [TestMethod]
   public void TestGetFacilities()
   {
     Assert.IsNotNull(assetsService);

     /* THIS ASSERTION FAILS when assetsService.GetFacilities has the [Transaction] attribute */ 
     Assert.IsNotNull(assetsService.FacilityDao);  

     IList<Facility> facilities = assetsService.GetFacilities();
     Assert.IsNotNull(facilities);
   }
  }
}
```

And here is the Service class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Namespace.Dao;
using Namespace.Entities;
using Namespace.Models;
using Spring.Transaction;
using Spring.Transaction.Interceptor;
using Facility = Namespace.Entities.Facility;

namespace Namespace.Services.Assets
{
  public class AssetsService
  {
    public AssetsService()
    {
     System.Console.Out.WriteLine("AssetsService created");
    }

    private FacilityDao _facilityDao;

    public FacilityDao FacilityDao
    {
      get
      {
        return _facilityDao;
      }
      set
      {
        _facilityDao = value;
      }
    }

    [Transaction(TransactionPropagation.Required, ReadOnly = true)]
    public IList<Facility> GetFacilities()
    {
      return _facilityDao.FetchAll();
     }
  }
}
```

And finally a condensed and amalgamated web.xml/applicationContext :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net">

 <db:provider id="DbProvider"
     provider="System.Data.SqlClient"
     connectionString="Data Source=localhost;...;"/>

  <object id="transactionManager"
        type="Spring.Data.NHibernate.HibernateTransactionManager, Spring.Data.NHibernate32">

    <property name="DbProvider" ref="DbProvider"/>
    <property name="SessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory"/>

</object>

 <tx:attribute-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

 <object type="Namespace.Dao.FacilityDao, Namespace" id="FacilityDao">
    <property name="SessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory"/>
 </object>

 <object type="Namespace.Services.Assets.AssetsService, Namespace" id="AssetsService">
   <property name="FacilityDao" ref="FacilityDao" />
 </object>

</objects>
```

EDIT:

Thanks to tips from Max and Marijn, I have now changed my AssetsService to use an interface rather than the actual implementation.  However, the problem persists.  Here are the revised details.

```
namespace Namespace.Services.Assets
{
  public class AssetsService
  {
    public AssetsService()
    {
      System.Console.Out.WriteLine("AssetsService created");
    }

    public IFacilityDao FacilityDao { get; set; }

    [Transaction(TransactionPropagation.Required, ReadOnly = true)]
    public IList<Facility> GetFacilities()
     {
      return FacilityDao.FetchAll();
    }

  }
}
```

The IFacilityDao:

```
namespace Namespace.Dao
{
    public interface IFacilityDao : IDao<Facility>
    {}

    public class FacilityDao : DaoBase<Facility>, IFacilityDao
    {

    }
}
```

IDao:

```
namespace Namespace.Dao
{
  public interface IDao<T>
  {
    T Fetch(int id);
    T FindByName(string name);
    IList<T> FetchAll();
    void SaveOrUpdate(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
  }
}
```

DaoBase:

```
namespace Namespace.Dao
{
    public abstract class DaoBase<T> : IDao<T>
    {
        public ISessionFactory SessionFactory { get; set; }

        public T Fetch(int id)
        {
            var result = SessionFactory
                      .GetCurrentSession()
                      .CreateCriteria(typeof(T))
                      .Add(Restrictions.Eq("ID", id))
                      .UniqueResult<T>();

            return result;
        }

     //.... 
}
```

}
[image: FacilityDao is not proxied]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: see update below*

Your `AssetService.FacilityDao` member should be of an interface type instead of the concrete `FacilityDao` type; otherwise spring.net will not be able to create a transaction proxy for interception. Try abstracting an `IFacilityDao` interface and change your `AssetService` to something like:

```
public class AssetsService
{
  public IFacilityDao FacilityDao { get; set; }
  // snip...
}
```

*Update*

The problem is that your `AssetService.GetFacilities` method cannot be proxied; try making it virtual (spring creates a decorator based proxy that proxies all *public **virtual*** methods if there are no interfaces to proxy); and if that fails, try introducing an `IAssetService` interface in a similar fashion I suggested for the dao's earlier. And inject it to an `IAssetService` property of your test.

Sorry I missed that earlier.

*Some additional explanation*

The failing `Assert.IsNotNull(assetsService.FacilityDao);` comes from the fact that the `AssetService` instance is injected on the test fixture ([autowired by type through spring testing infrastructure](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/testing.html#testing-fixture-di)). Because of the transaction attribute, an *aop proxy* is injected. The *target* of this proxy is the "real" object that has a `FacilityDao` injected into it.

But the `assetsService` of your assertion is *the aop proxy*. Initially you did not have any interfaces specified on your `AssetService` class and spring [created a decorator proxy](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxy-mechanism) - a proxy that inherits from `AssetService`, with all virtual methods overridden and delegated to the target object.

The assertion returns null, because on this proxy the facility dao is never injected.

The assertion didn't return null without the transaction attribute applied, because the "unproxied" object was injected.

Comment: See my update; make `GetFacilities` virtual or create `IAssetService` interface.

Answer (score 0):

Marijin is right: if you want to use Spring.NET's capability of AOP (and using transaction attributes ist basically AOP) your beans (in Java terms) need to implement an interface. 
The reason for that is that Spring.NET creates a proxy object which is technically an instance of some class which is created during runtime. The NullReferenceException is thrown because .NET cannot cast this proxy class to your concrete type. This can be only accomplished by using interfaces.